# How to center a block in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to center a 940px widget in my page.
In the layout panel it's not possible to set `Left` and `Right` to `auto` at the same time.

So far I can only attach a block to left or right. Is it possible to center it to have all the element to stay in the center on large display like stackoverflow.com  ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do that. An approach that you can take is to change the page layout to vertical.

[image]

Then change the widget's Layout align attribute value to center.

[image]

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Yes, going to vertical layout helped me !